# Swift - Load information from Core Data faster

Tags: core-data, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Hey how to get big amount of information like 1000 rows without stuck?
I try with this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
//here code
})
```

but when I executed the request `self.context.executeFetchRequest` it returns me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I have an error and I have to add `self.` in front of the function.

```
    let queue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
 dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
                 //code
        })
```

but also I get the same error...

I use NSFetchRequest and I add the results in NSArray and I loop the results in for loop and in the loop I sort results in a dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 records is not very much for Core Data. Just fetch them on the thread.

I would not advise to "sort results in a dictionaries". You should think how your app logic interacts with the data and simply fetch the objects you need from the Core Data persistent store.

For example, if you want to display 1000 lines in a table view, use `NSFetchedResultsController´ which is optimized for this sort of situation - so you will avoid memory and performance issues without any work.

If you really need threading with Core Data (which I doubt) I would advise not to start with GCD but to use Core Data's own concurrency APIs, such as `performBlock` and global queue child contexts. But most likely you won't have to worry about those.

Finally, your error is really referring to some code that you have not posted. It has to do with Swift's optionals. For example, if you declare a variable as type `variable : String?` (or you use an API that returns such a type), you can unwrap it with `variable!` if you are sure it is not `nil` . If it is `nil` you will get the above crash.

Comment: I am getting data from Core Data as NSData and unarchive with NSKeyedUnarchived the archive contains Dictionary<String, AnyObject> and this dictionary loads my tableview, tableview is in PageViewController which loads different Dictionaries and when I swipe between pages I have 1.5-2 seconds stuck, I am getting hundreds of dictionaries from Core Data and I add them in 1 dictionary and send it in pageviewcontroller to show all data

Comment: Yes, sounds like NSFetchedResultsController is for you. Get rid of the archived dictionaries and store the primitive values in Core Data instead.

Comment: I can't store primitive values my all code wants to store dict["(value) / \(valueUnit)"] = 55 and I have to save 3 things example:
dict["apple / pieces"] = 4 and I want to count If I have multiple times apple / pieces how is if its 5 times 5x4=20 pieces, I have orange pieces and kiwi pieces and I want to get all pieces

Comment: Yes, sounds like the primitive values directly in Core Data is the way to go.  (Yes, you can!) You need to design your data model intelligently in order to avoid the absurd extra and unnecessary work you burdening the CPU with.

Comment: If I make other entities and store data there my fecthedrequests will get 3 times more than now and I have to pass a lot of data in variables to connect everything, that means +2000 lines of code. Maybe if I do it it will make the app slower than now...

Comment: It would make it much faster. You can search in the data directly, not indirectly via decoded NSData. IMO, this refactoring is not only advisable, but necessary.

Comment: I have to add all mu values in strings or what ? Can you give me an examples with I can work faster?

Comment: I don't know what data you are having in the dictionaries, but I doubt it is very complex. Just look at the Core Data sample apps by Apple, e.g. CoreDataBooks. - Anyway, take my advise and abandon your setup. You will be grateful later. You can ask a new question when you have a prototype.

Comment: This is a perfect example for which a solid Core Data model is most suitable. Your NSData /Dictionary approach is ludicrous and predictably leads to a performance nightmare. Stop wasting time on SOF and get to work! :-)